# JSON.net SelectToken formatting

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have the following xml :-

```
<AgentBookingStatusResponse>
  <Eta>2012-11-19T15:40:15.0819269+00:00</Eta>
</AgentBookingStatusResponse>
```

I read this into a `JObject` and then convert it to a string using the following code :

```
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_document);

 var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

 var eta = (string) jsonResponse.SelectToken("AgentBookingStatusResponse.Eta") ?? null;
```

The issue i am getting is that there is some implicit formatting happening when doing this as eta has the value : `11/19/2012 15:40:15`

I would like to keep the same format as in the XML.

How do i accomplish this and if I wanted to change format to UK time how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following by using the `JsonConvert` class in Newtonsoft's JSON.NET. To get your data in JSON, then you can `Deserialize` it into an Object by using the `RootClass` as a template.

Finally do `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")` to grab United Kingdom's date format then display it or do whatever you wish.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class AgentBookingStatusResponse
    {
        public DateTime Eta { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootData
    {
        public AgentBookingStatusResponse AgentBookingStatusResponse { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          string testXMLData = @"<AgentBookingStatusResponse><Eta>2012-11-19T15:40:15.0819269+00:00</Eta></AgentBookingStatusResponse>";  

          XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
          doc.LoadXml(testXMLData);
          string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

          //Deserialize to RootData Object
          var dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootData>(jsonText);

          var datetime = new DateTime();
          datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(dataObj.AgentBookingStatusResponse.Eta);
          CultureInfo uk = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
          string ukDate = datetime.ToString("O", uk);

          Console.WriteLine(ukDate);
          Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

`jsonText` Output:

```
{
    "AgentBookingStatusResponse": {
        "Eta": "2012-11-19T15:40:15.0819269+00:00"
    }
}
```

`ukDate` Output:

```
2012-11-19T10:40:15.0819269-05:00
```

**UPDATE**

We can also do this without first creating a RootClass by using `JObject` from `Newtonsoft JSON.NET`.

In this case we would first convert the XML to JSON using `JsonConvert.SerializeXMLNode()` then we can use `JObject.Parse()` Like so.

```
  string testXMLData = @"<AgentBookingStatusResponse><Eta>2012-11-19T15:40:15.0819269+00:00</Eta></AgentBookingStatusResponse>";  

  //First we convert this XML to JSON
  var doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(testXMLData);
  string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

  //Then we use JObject to parse the converted JSON data to an Object
  JObject jsonDataObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

  //Grab Token "Eta" and convert to DateTime Object
  var dateTimeToken = Convert.ToDateTime(jsonDataObj.SelectToken("AgentBookingStatusResponse.Eta"));

  //DateTime Object to a string with UK Culture information and proper Formatting
  var ukDateTime = dateTimeToken.ToString("O", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

`ukDateTime` Output:

```
2012-11-19T10:40:15.0819269-05:00
```

Documentation can be found [Here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to achieve this through the SelectToken method of JObject? Surely there must be a way to format string dates through it?

Comment: @macca18 I updated the answer. I don't believe there is a way to directly format dates with `SelectToken`. There is only one method overload which allows an error when no match for token.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it as follows:

```
var eta = (string)jsonResponse.SelectToken("AgentBookingStatusResponse").SelectToken("Eta");
```